# C++ EOF? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, eof

Don't really know what EOF is.

I'm a beginner. My teacher just asked me not to use it for 'extra credit'.

I'm using urlmon. Here is an example of my code. I've researched and couldn't find anything of use.

If someone could point out where I'm using EOF, that would be amazing. If you could tell me an alternative, that'll be even better.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <string>
#include <urlmon.h>

typedef HRESULT (WINAPI* lpURLDownloadToFile) (LPUNKNOWN pCaller,
    LPCTSTR szURL,
    LPCTSTR szFileName,
    DWORD dwReserved,
    LPBINDSTATUSCALLBACK lpfnCB);

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

void download()
{
    lpURLDownloadToFile URLDownloadToFile;

    HMODULE hUrlmon = LoadLibrary("URLMON.DLL");

    URLDownloadToFile = (lpURLDownloadToFile)GetProcAddress(hUrlmon, "URLDownloadToFileA");

    URLDownloadToFile(0, "http://website.com/hi.mov", "hi.mov", 0, 0);

    return;
}
```

Comment: EOF means `End of File`: http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Files/End.htm

Comment: **EOF** means *end of file*.

Your code is not directly concerned with EOF since you're downloading the complete file contents in one chunk. The code that you invoke to do that, however, downloads smaller pieces, and probably deals with EOF to determine when it's finished. Alternatively it can be keeping track of total download size. In that case even lower level code has to deal with EOF, to make sure that things don't hang for a too-short download.

Comment: You're not using it. In fact, you're not doing anything since you have no `main` function. It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: you're not reading anything from file so there's no EOF to care. When reading EOF is a signal saying that you're reading passed the end of file, i.e. nothing more to read, so you must stop

Answer (score 0):

When you want to read from a file the program needs to stop when it reaches the end of the file. Getc() returns a special value known as EOF, when it tries to read a character but the end of the file has been reached.